# Images are not showing after deploying to Amazon EBS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I deployed a Rails app (5.1) using Puma server. In development, the images are showing but after I deployed the app to Amazon Cloud (production) the images were not showing at all except some broken image icon.

I tried these:

1. Changed `config.assets.compile` to `true`,
2. Run `bundle exec rack assets:precompile` but no luck.

Comment: What exact images do you mean? Dynamic images or static images that are part of your design?

Comment: Can you let us know what Storage you use? I am guessing that there are probably some storage restrictions or some additional configuration requried to properly store images. It might be that this is what Heroku does, they keep your images for 30 minutes and, if on a basic plan, they delete them. I's hard to say, though, anything more without more information about your setup.

Comment: I’m using Elastic Beanstalk web server platform puma with Ruby 2.5 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2.7.1.

Comment: I’m using Elastic Beanstalk web server platform puma with Ruby 2.5 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2.7.1. It doesn’t show the static images like home page logo and some aside images.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: I just inspected the home page in Safari and it read's "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (assets/photo_lighting.jpg)